# Polynomial in Lisp

Tags: function, math, recursion, lisp, polynomial-math

People, help me with this **lisp** function. There is a list with polynomial coefficients. This function needs to calculate value of polynomial.

```
Pol (x list)
```

for example `(Pol 2 '(3 5 2))` => 17

Comment: Is this homework for a class, or legitimate question?

Comment: This is for a class. I solved many other problems but i can't believe i can't solve this one. Problem is that we can't use exp function. I tried to find another solution but recursion always makes a problem with first parameter.                                                                     (defun pol (x list) (cond ((null list) '0) (t (+ (* x (car list)) (pol (* x x) (cdr list)))) ) )

(defun polynom (x list) (+ (car list) (pol x (cdr list))) )         this is my try

Comment: @user, can you post your try as formatted code in your question? (We could try to copy it from your comment, but we have no hope of indenting it properly without the source.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Horner's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Comment: (defun polynom (x list) (cond ((null list) '0) (t (+ (car list) (* x (polynom x (cdr list))))) ) ) Thanks man for the link. I solved it.